# Google Sheets Query WHERE clause just returns first row of data

Tags: sql, google-sheets

I have a sheet which I am trying to use to show an overview of students results in a number of subjects, with each student and their results in separate rows.

OVERVIEW

- studentID, English, Maths, etc
- 1, result1, result2, etc
- 2, result3, result4, etc

The result data comes from another system and is in a separate sheet. Each result for each subject is a separate row where the first column is the student ID, the second is the subject and the third is the result.

RESULTSET

- 1, ENGLISH, result 1
- 1, MATHS, result 2
- etc.

I've been trying various forms of a query like this
`=query(RESULTSET!A1:C,"SELECT C WHERE A = '1' AND B = 'ENGLISH'",1)` but the query only ever returns the first result from the first row of data in RESULTSET.

Here is a link to a test spreadsheet containing data and queries that reproduces the issue: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15xLAyHumL2pC8mRfA4Qs9xMyrWZvK86kmoi2kBWnB34/edit?usp=sharing

I am expecting to see results from the result set that matches each student ID and subject, but I am only ever seeing the first result irrespective of ID or subject.

Comment: Remove '' from the int (1) and remove the 1 at the end of the query, that should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the reference to column A and set the headers argument in query() to zero. In B2 try

```
=iferror(query('result set 1'!$A$1:$C58,"SELECT C WHERE A = "&$A2&" AND B = '"&UPPER(B$1)&"'",0))
```

Fill down to the right and down as far as needed and see if that works?

Another option would be to use in B2

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup($A$2:$A$8&B$1, {'result set 1'!$A:$A&'result set 1'!$B:$B, 'result set 1'!$C:$C}, 2, 0)))
```

and fill to the right (make sure there is no data below row 2).

Comment: =iferror(query('result set 1'!$A$1:$C58,"SELECT C WHERE A = "&$A2&" AND B = '"&UPPER(B$1)&"'",0)) thanks, that has worked perfectly.